# Getting Parse Object ID from onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I am currently working on an app which contains a friends list when logged in and user profiles. When the user clicks on a friend in the friends list, I would like them to be directed to a profile page for this friend. To do this, I have been trying to extract the specific object id from the user that is clicked on in the list view and then pass that onto the next activity where I use it to run a query for all the users other attributes (name, email, hometown, etc.). I have figured out how to pass along data through intents but I am having all sorts of trouble obtaining the user id from the list item clicked. My onItemCLick code is below.

```

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ParseObject item = (ParseObject) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    String objectID = item.getObjectId().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FriendsProfileActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", objectID);
    startActivity(intent);
```

```

I have also tried something of this sort to not avail.

```

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

     ParseObject item = (ParseObject) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
     item.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
         @Override
         public void done(ParseException e) {
             if(e == null) {
                 String objectID = item.getObjectId();
                 Log.e(TAG, objectID);

                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FriendsProfileActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("ID", objectID);
                 startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

```

In both cases, the app crashes when I click on the user in the list view. How can I succesfully pull the object ID from the user clicked on and pass it along?

Edit: Here is the logcat error.

`Process: com.richluick.ribbit, PID: 2194
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseObject
            at com.richluick.ribbit.FriendsFragment.onListItemClick(FriendsFragment.java:83)
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Edit: Here is the full code for the activity including the query and list adapter.
    package com.richluick.ribbit;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import java.util.List;

public class FriendsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = FriendsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    protected List<ParseUser> mFriends;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query =  mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
        query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
                getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                if (e == null) {
                    mFriends = friends;

                    String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                        usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                        i++;
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usernames);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getListView().getContext());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setMessage(e.getMessage())
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        final ParseObject item = (ParseObject) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        item.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) {
                    String objectID = item.getObjectId();
                    Log.e(TAG, objectID);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FriendsProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", objectID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

}
```

}

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Post Yout LogCat to see the exeption or error.

Comment: Please post the rest of the code in the activity - that is, the code that makes the query and loads the listview.  It would help in understanding your problem - the logcat error seems to imply that what's being held in the adapter are Strings to begin with, not ParseObjects

Comment: Okay, posted the code for the whole activity above. Based on the logcat I had a similar feeling that the problem was something like that.

Comment: Yep, the adapter only knows the names of the users, nothing more. If your insist moving on with that code, then you should store a list of users and then call `mUserList.get(position)` in `onListItemClick()`. Of course this list should be stored in the exact same order as the usernames are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at ParseQueryAdapter

Docs: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-queryadapter

Tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter

API: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html.

Also I would recommend EventBus to pass the ParseObject to the next Activity https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus.

Then you can do:

Adapter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FriendsProfileActivity.class);
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(YourParseObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

Anywhere in FriendsProfileActivity:

```
ParseObject yourParseObject = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(ParseObject.class);
```

If you move on to using subclasses in parse.com, then any subclass can be sent via the EventBus this way.

Example code - untested but should be close to what you want

**The ParseQueryAdapter:**

The layout for R.layout.adapter_item_friend - can be customized but nothing fancy here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="item" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Adapter:

```
public class ParseUserFriendsAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> {

    private static final String TAG = ParseUserFriendsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public ParseUserFriendsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                ParseRelation<ParseUser> friendsRelation = currentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query =  friendsRelation.getQuery();
                query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @InjectView(R.id.text) TextView text;

    @Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseUser user, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_item_friend,
                    null);
        }

        super.getItemView(user, v, parent);

        ButterKnife.inject(this, v);

        text.setText(user.getUsername());


        return v;

    }

}
```

**I am using a regular fragment containing a ListView in it's layout:**

R.layout.yourfriendslistlayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The important parts of the code in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    mAdapter = new ParseUserFriendsAdapter(getActivity());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@InjectView(R.id.listview) ListView mListView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.yourfriendslistlayout, container, false);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

    /** Setting the list adapter for the ListFragment */
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Now it is easy to get the ParseObject that is clicked
            ParseUser friend = mAdapter.getItem(position);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked " + friend.getObjectId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(friend);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    FriendsProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Optional addition to the fragment code:

```
/* 
 *This last part automatically sets the load indicator whenever parse performs a query 
 */
private final OnQueryLoadListener<ParseUser> queryListener = new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseUser>() {

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(List<ParseUser> arg0, Exception arg1) {
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(queryListener);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mAdapter.removeOnQueryLoadListener(queryListener);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and links. That all seems great for when I want to further customize the query results. However, before I get that far ahead, I need a way to extract the object ID from the userobject that is clicked on in the listview and store it in a variable to then pass along. Would you have any insight on this? Thanks.

Comment: this answer doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: @user2163298 yes it does.. It adds a parseobject to each list item. Will give an example soon. Am not at my computer at the moment

Comment: @user2163298 think it is a bit unfair to downvote an answer just because you do not understand it .. anyways .. now there is some code showing the idea

Comment: @cYrixmorten - I fully understand what you were trying to convey.  In fact, I have had this issue many times myself, and I circumvent it by filling a separate ArrayList with the objectIds that correspond to the ParseObjects in order.  Then when I click on an item, I extract the objectID out of the String ArrayList that is in the same position as the item I just clicked, and send the ID over to the next Activity.  I actually agree with your recommendation of EventBus, and will use it myself in the future, so thank you for that!

Comment: @cYrixmorten - I will remove my downvote, however I still maintain that your original answer did not satisfy OP's original question - the logcat error was clear that something was fishy with his listview, which is why I asked him to post more code - your suggestion to read the docs and use EventBus did not acknowledge the real issue at hand

Comment: @cYrixmorten - I also believe your use of EventBus and ButterKnife may be confusing to OP... a very speculative upvote you get my good sir

Comment: @user2163298 I get your point and yes regarding ButterKnife .. To be honest i just didnt want to reqwrite it to the not use ButterKnife and think that the code is more readable that way :) but you might be right

Comment: @user2163298 btw EventBus is as simple as I just posted in the first answer. This way he can get the full object shipped to the next Activity without the need to look up the user from an objectId.

Comment: @cYrixmorten thats actually great - I really am going to start using that, I have not yet really had a way to pass an object from one activity to another and I frequently have a need to, thank you for inadvertently introducing me to that.  While we're on the subject, what's ButterKnife all about? I've never heard of that either

Comment: @user2163298 try googling android butterknife. It is just a smart way to inject views. It is also really simple. For instance, if you have a button in the layout, then to use it you have to do: 1) findViewById 2) save in fjeld variable 3) define an onclicklistener.. All in all minimum about 8 lines of code. With butterknife it is '@OnClick(R.id.myButton) public void clicked(Button button) {}'

Comment: @cYrixmorten - wow that sounds pretty groovy I will have to check that out - thanks a lot man

Comment: @user2163298 While we are at it, you should also have a look at Dagger http://square.github.io/dagger/ Thought it is rather complicated to learn, it was all worth it for me. It provides Dependency Injection of objects in Android.`

Comment: Alright thanks for all the help guys! Im away for the labor day weekend but I will implement this into my project first thing when I get back. The eventbus way of shipping the whole object over seems to make alot of sense now that you explained it. I'll give it a shot and report back!

Comment: Alright, so finally back at it after a long labor day weekend. The code posted with EventBus and ButterKnife in fact was a tad confusing to me as a beginner and I have many questions after reading through that code. With that in mind I tried @user2163298 method of putting the IDs in an ArrayList with great success! However, it seems you both agree that using EventBus is ultimately a better method so once I finish going through with this project I will go back and spend some more time understanding how it works.

Comment: @RichLuick Thank you for the feedback. Yeah the separate ArrayList is indeed easier and ButterKnife is just a nice to have. When you eventually get to take a look at EventBus, then it actually is as simple as it looks: 1 line to send the object onto the EventBus and 1 line to retrieve it again in any other place in your code. I have loved it as I am using fairly complex parse subclasses with a lot of state. Would be a nightmare to keep looking up objectIds for every detail view in my app. Glad you got it working :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Simple use a textview in your list item, and populate it with ObjectID of object in getItemView() of your adapter and set its visibility to View.GONE

Then in onItemClickListener, call getText() of this textview.

In this way you can get objectId in your method and pass it along with intent.