# ParseObject subclass cannot make changes in constructor

Tags: android, constructor, parse-platform, subclass

I have a ParseObject subclass with a constructor that tries to set a field with a new UUID:

```
@ParseClassName("Results")
public class Results extends ParseObject {
    public static final String FIELD_UUID = "uuid";

    public Results() {
        // Default constructor
        setUuid();
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return getString(FIELD_UUID);
    }

    public void setUuid() {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        put(FIELD_UUID, uuid.toString());
    }

    ...
}
```

However, apparently I cannot call `setUuid()` in the constructor as the follow error occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ParseObject subclass default constructor must not make changes to the object that cause it to be dirty.
```

I'd prefer to have the UUID set automatically every time a new `Results` object is created instead of creating a new object, then calling `setUuid()`.  Is this possible to do, or is there a workaround?

Comment: If I was you I would use Cloud Code. Automatically generate the UUID in `beforeSave` of Results. Why the need of a UUID? Thinking you have ObjectId, which is unique per application.

Comment: I would use objectId but it is null until it is saved to the cloud.  All my ParseObjects are saved in the local datastore.  I've been going off of the Offline Todo list tutorial as well.  In the cases where a user hasn't signed up or if there's no connectivity, I need a local way of creating relationships between my ParseObject subclasses.  The UUID method seems to be the best way.

Comment: I use local datastore as well but I do not need anything like this .. can u come with a concrete example how/why you need this? Also if both objects are newly created, then adding dependencies among them should be valid, despite no objectId.

Comment: Well, I see I can add pointer fields instead.  Is that what is recommended?  An example of why I used UUIDs is when a ParseObject's data needs to be passed between activities.  I figured passing and id via intents across activities was better than passing whole ParseObjects.

Comment: Pointers is definitely the way to go. The best mehod I have found is to use EventBus to pass whole ParseObjects, you will find an example in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574243/getting-parse-object-id-from-onlistitemclick/25574982#25574982 it is really simple and saves you the trouble of doing extra queries to locate the passed object.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks so much for the help!  Definitely clears things up.  If you want to post your response as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers is definitely the way to go.

The best mehod I have found is to use EventBus to pass whole ParseObjects, you will find an example in my answer to this question: [Getting Parse Object ID from onListItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574243/getting-parse-object-id-from-onlistitemclick/25574982#25574982)

It is really simple and saves you the trouble of doing extra queries to locate the passed object.